# Скроллируемый ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Необходимо получить большой объем данных (более 2 миллионов записей). База MySQL. Пытался сделать через скроллируемый ResultSet.

```
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("begin");

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "user", "password");            

        st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

        rs = st.executeQuery("select ID, NAME from TABLE_NAME");

        rs.isBeforeFirst();
        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString("ID") + " : " + rs.getString("NAME"));
        }

        System.out.println("end");
    } finally{
        if(rs != null) rs.close();
        if(st != null) st.close();
        if(con != null) con.close();
    }
```

Ошибка

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

WARNING Failed to accept a connection.: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhad limit exceeded

ERROR java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Подскажите как исправить.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что проблема не в ResultSet, а в другом месте. Т.к. скроллируемый ResultSet вряд ли станет причиной OutOfMemoryError.
Хотя я могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html) на английском (читать раздел `ResultSet`). Если вкратце, то по умолчанию MySQL вычитывает весь результат в память. Может помочь такой код:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement(java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
          java.sql.ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
stmt.setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Там есть подводные камни, связанные с блокировкой. Когда у нас встала такая проблема, подводные камни оказались очень неприятными, и мы в итоге перешли на обход таблицы по частям с помощью `LIMIT a,b` либо `WHERE ID BETWEEN x AND y`. Второй вариант обычно быстрее, но надо заранее знать диапазон идентификаторов и надеяться, что среди них немного пропусков.

Answer (score 1):

Пробовали выделить больше памяти Java-машине?

- `-Xms<размер>` - начальный размер кучи.
- `-Xmx<размер>` - максимальный размер кучи.
- `-Xss<размер>` - размер Thread стека.

Пример:

```
java -Xms16m -Xmx32m YourAppClass
```